# Show all images in a view "details" in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to show all my images in my db but for some reason that I don't understand I can't... if someone can help me, I would appreciate it.... I'm new in ASP.NET MVC, I know a few things but that's all

**My View Detail**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="@Url.Action("PaginasComics", "Comics", new {IdC = Model.Pages})" />
    </div>
</div>
```

My view is not an `IEnumerable<>` view, I been thinking in create a partial view and put in this part but i dont know if will work and i dont know how...

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult PaginasComics(string IdPagina)
    {
        var PaginasC = db.Paginas.Where(x => x.IdPaginaC.ToString() == IdPagina).FirstOrDefault();
        return File(PaginasC.Paginas, "imagen/jpeg", string.Format("{0}.jpg", IdPagina));

    }
```

This is how I show the images, but is not working... I have the same code to "PORTADA" in model comics and it's work... I'm not really good work with arrays, maybe that's what I need.

**Models**

```
public class Comics
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int IdComics { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; } //title
    public byte[] Portada { get; set; } //cover
    public DateTime FechadeEstreno { get; set; } //date release

    public ICollection<PaginasComics> Pages { get; set; }


}

public class PaginasComics
{

    public int IdPaginaC { get; set; }
    public byte[] Paginas {get; set;}
    public int Id_Comic { get; set; } //foreig key of comics

   // here i save all the images
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

your url action, you passing IdC as parameters but your controllers asked for IdPagina parameter. try changes the url signature as requested in controller

```
<img src="@Url.Action("PaginasComics", "Comics", new {IdPagina = Model.Pages})" />
```

Comment: i forget fix this when i post the problem, but i try it and didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Issue was there you didn't use correctly qoutes in url.Action. And second action method parameter name should match with the parameter you defined in the url.action.
**My View Detail**

**For getting multiple images from Action method and show in the View change this like:**

```
@{
   foreach(var pageId in Model.Pages){
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="@Url.Action('PaginasComics', 'Comics', new {IdPagina = pageId })" />
        </div>
    </div>
   }

 }
```

**For getting single image from Action method and show in the View change this like:**

```
@{
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="@Url.Action('PaginasComics', 'Comics', new {IdPagina = Model.Pages })" />
        </div>
    </div>
   }
```